# returning iDisposable from method - whos is responsible for disposing?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Given the following code:

```
    using (var webResponse = GenerateWebrequest(postURL, postParameters))
        {
            using (var stream = webResponse.GetResponse())
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    xmlDoc.Load(stream);
                }
            }

            webResponse.Close();
        }
```

which calls the method:

```
private HttpWebResponse GetResponse(string postUrl, byte[] formData)
    {
       var request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
       //other code to set up request here...

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
```

My question is basically this:

The calling code wraps the method call in a using and disposes of the response stream.

But what should happen if request.GetResponse() in the GenerateWebrequest fails?
Should I simply wrap it in a try catch? What do i return then?

Comment: No.  If the method fails then it must throw an exception.  No need to worry about returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special pattern to use for methods returning `IDisposable` objects:

```
HttpWebRequest tmpRequest;
try
{
  tmpRequest = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebReqeust;

  // Whatever other stuff...

  // When all other work is done. No code that can cause an exception
  // should exist below this line.
  var returnRequest = tmpReqeust;
  tmpRequest = null;

  return returnRequest;
}
finally
{
  if(tmpRequest != null)
    tmpRequest.Dispose();
}
```

The pattern also works for constructors creating nested `IDisposable` objects and for methods creating multiple `IDisposable` objects.

Comment: The above pattern is semantically correct and I don't know of any semantically-correct pattern that's much nicer, but it's still ugly.  Using a `success` flag and having a `finally` block dispose of things if `success` is false would allow nicer refactoring if/when C# adds a clean syntax for a `finally` block to determine whether its `try` block succeeded without affecting the first-pass exception handling sequence.